# How to move a View in my LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-gui

I have a linear layout and small view (50px - 50px), all I want to do is to move this view in to the parent (linear layout in my case). It doesn't have to be linear layout but if possible I want my wrapper to be linear layout.
[image]

What is the right way to move a drawable in the parent ?
my small green view is an image (R.drawable.myimage) and I want to be able to easily move this image in the parent, the movement should me smooth

Comment: are you talking about animating this view?

Comment: well all I want to do is to move from right to left (basically yes like an animation)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is the built-in [`TranslateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html).

If you're moving in straight lines, it works fine.

You may need to be more specific about your needs: when will it animate? What types of paths will it follow?